# While debugging logic app function on my local machine I am getting ESOCKET error

Tags: azure, logic

Hi guys while I am trying to debug a logic app function on my local machine it is giving me a Esocket error. I was working on a mac machine and everything works out fine recently shifted to a windows machine tried setting up the dev environment and it doesn't let me debug the function locally. I am pushing a csv file into the datbase. The function just reads the csv file which is "," delimited and using the generated sql schema and header row patterns it loads onto the staging table.

[This is what it shows when I debug it and push data through insomnia.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn9el.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14rEx.png)

This is the exact copy of the code which I am writing. IT fails on the const connection = new sql.connectionPool command.

```
const mu = require("../lib/myUtil");    
const sql = require('mssql');        
const csv = require('csvtojson');    
const settings = require('../lib/settings');    

module.exports = async function(context, req) {
    context.log('Write Air BnB Roster.');

if (req.body.data) {
    var incomingData = req.body.data;
    var header_names = [];

    var records = await csv({ maxRowLength: 65535 }).fromString(incomingData).on('header', (header) => {
        header_names = header;
    }).on('error', (err) => {
        console.log("csv err: " + err)
    });

    console.log("parsed data: " + records.length);

    //Process Empty Data
    if (records.length == 0) {
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: {
                "total": records.length,
                "rowsAffected": 0,
                "headerCount": header_names.length
            }
        };
        return;

}
    const conn = new sql.ConnectionPool(settings.prodDBOpts);
    await conn.connect();  

    // --------- Change Table Name ---------
    const table = new sql.Table('[dbo].[stg_arise_employee]');
    table.create = false;
    // --------- Paste Below --------------
    table.columns.add('RecordDate', sql.DateTime, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('IBID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('IBName', sql.VarChar(60), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('AriseUserID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('CSPID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Firstname', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Lastname', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('email', sql.VarChar(60), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Role', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('SupportResourceAriseUSERID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('SupportResourceCSPID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('SupportResourceName', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Wave', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('WaveStartDate', sql.DateTime, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Application', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('ApplicationID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('OffboardDate', sql.DateTime, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('AirbnbID', sql.Int, { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('ZendeskID', sql.VarChar(20), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('ScorebuddyID', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield4', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield5', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield6', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield7', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield8', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield9', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })
    table.columns.add('Customfield10', sql.VarChar(40), { nullable: true })


    // ---------  Paste Above --------- 
    records.forEach((data) => {
        table.rows.add(
            //  --------- PASTE BELOW --------- 
            mu.validateDate2(data['RecordDate']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['IBID']),
            mu.validateString(data['IB Name']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['Arise UserID']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['CSPID']),
            mu.validateName2(data['Firstname']),
            mu.validateName2(data['Lastname']),
            mu.validateString(data['email']),
            mu.validateString(data['Role']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['SupportResourceAriseUSERID']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['SupportResourceCSPID']),
            mu.validateString(data['SupportResourceName']),
            mu.validateString(data['Wave']),
            mu.validateDate3(data['Wave Start Date']),
            mu.validateProgram(data['Application']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['Application ID']),
            mu.validateDate2(data['Offboard Date']),
            mu.validateNumber(data['AirbnbID']),
            mu.validateString(data['ZendeskID']),
            mu.validateString(data['Scorebuddy ID']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield4']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield5']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield6']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield7']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield8']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield9']),
            mu.validateString(data['Customfield10'])
            //  --------- PASTE ABOVE --------- 
        );
    });

    context.log("Async function started!");
    const request = new sql.Request(conn);

    try {
        const results = await request.bulk(table);
        context.log("Rows affected: " + results.rowsAffected);

        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            /* Defaults to 200 */
            body: {
                "total": records.length,
                "rowsAffected": results.rowsAffected,
                "headerCount": header_names.length
            }
        };

        await conn.close();
        console.log("connection closed.")
    } catch (error) {
        context.log(error);
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: error
        };
    }
} else {
    context.res = {
        status: 200,
        /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: {
            "total": 0,
            "rowsAffected": 0,
            "headerCount": 0
        }
    };
}
};
```

Comment: Could you add more details like what code you are trying to execute and purpose of the code?

Comment: The code is written in javascript and what it really doing is picking the file from ftp/email and then reads the said file and bulk loads the data on our database/staging table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update :  I was running node version 12.x.x I downgraded my node to version 10.14.1 and it works I guess the version was not compatible with the libraries I was using.